# plt.legend() when plotting multiple dataframes in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

suppose i have three dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,2,3], "B" : [4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [2,5,3], "B" : [7,3,1]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,2,1], "B" : [5,3,6]})
```

I put all three dataframes in a list to perform an identical operation on all three dataframes

```
dframes = [df1, df2, df3]
for frame in dframes:
   frame["C"] = frame["A"] + frame["B"]
   plt.plot(frame["C"])
```

works like a charm. my problem: when i want to add a legend.
plt.legend() throws

> No artists with labels found to put in legend.

plt.legend(frame) uses the names of the columns in the dataframes, i.e.,

> "A", "B" & "C"

and not as desired

> "df1", "df2", "df3"

how can i grab the correct line handles  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the message you've received after trying [`plt.legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html), the function is looking for `labels`. So, let's supply them inside [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) by setting the `label` parameter.

We can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get index values for the `dfs` in your list `dframes` as well, to be used inside the [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

```
dframes = [df1, df2, df3]
for i, frame in enumerate(dframes):
   frame["C"] = frame["A"] + frame["B"]
   plt.plot(frame["C"], label=f'df{i+1}') # setting the label: `df1`, `df2`, `df3`
   
plt.legend() # or `plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1,1])` to move it outside of the plot
plt.show()
```

**Result**

[image: plot with labels]

---

Update. Example using a dict and using the keys for the labels:

```
dframes = {'ll_800': df1, 'll_600wo_200': df2, 'wo_800': df3}
for k, v in dframes.items():
    v["C"] = v["A"] + v["B"]
    plt.plot(v["C"], label=k)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1,1])
plt.show()
```

**Result**

[image: plot with legend outside]

Comment: thanks!  my dataframes are not named df1 - df3 but have individual names of ll_800, ll_600wo_200, wo_800  is there a way to link the index values from enumerate to a list in which the actual names are stored?

Comment: I would use a dict; see the updated answer. So, `df1` is now stored as the value for `dframes['ll_800']`, etc. But you could also make a separate list, like: `my_list = ['ll_800', 'll_600wo_200', 'wo_800']` and then inside `for i, frame in enumerate(dframes):` we can use the `i` to access the list items. So, it would be `label=my_list[i]` in that case.